# Why scipy doesn't have any built-in methods to find maximum?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I recently used the sciPy library to find a maximum of a function. But it only provides methods for finding the minimum ([Optimization and root finding - sciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html)). Of course, I can always find the maximum by finding the minimum of the negative of my function.

But my question is why built-in methods are for minimum, not maximum? Is there any special reason to provide built-in optimization methods for the minimum or is it just randomly chosen?

Comment: Just convention.